# How do I get [item].[equation] number for numbering homework problems?

Tags: equations, numbering

I am doing my homework, and each of the problems is an "item", part of an itemized list. Each problem has some equations which I am numbering. I want the numbers to look like [item].[equation-number]. I am aware of the command numberwithin, but it doesn't work for items, throwing compiling errors. Code provided below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

%\numberwithin{equation}{item}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

   \item 
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
    We have the following amazing equation: \[ a = 6. \numberthis\label{p1}\]
    We also have this beautiful equation: \[a1 = 17. \numberthis\label{p1-2}\]


   \item 
   \setcounter{equation}{0}
   More amazingness here: \[ b = 7.\numberthis\label{p2}\]


\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

(Uncomment the line numberwithin... and compile to see the error). I am using numberthis as a new command that I found the code for somewhere on tex stackexchange, and I'd prefer to not remove it, since it works very well for me across various math environments.

What I want to see is (1.1), (1.2) ... for Problem 1, (2.1), (2.2)... for Problem 2, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know the correct counter name, wich is `enumi` for the first level of `enumerate`. And if you use an environment like `equation`, wich automatically numbers the equation, you don't need additional macros.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\numberwithin{equation}{enumi}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
    We have the following amazing equation:
    \begin{equation}
        a = 6.         \label{p1}
    \end{equation}
    We also have this beautiful equation:
    \begin{equation}
        a1 = 17.       \label{p1-2}
    \end{equation}

\item 
    More amazingness here:
    \begin{equation}
        b = 7.        \label{p2}
    \end{equation}


\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is beautiful, works exactly as I want! Thanks! :)